# Ruby on rails curl -k -u

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I am trying to do the equivalent of

```
 curl -u username -k https://my-site.com
```

So far I have benn following http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html. I have tried:

```
uri = URI('https://my-site.com')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```

I am getting SSL errors.
I can curl it in the terminal.
Not sure how to supply a password and username

```
req.basic_auth 'user', 'password'
```

didn't help.

Errors I am getting:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're getting SSL errors, post them here. That may be the problem

Comment: done, I am pretty sure I am having trouble calling the API. curl -u username -k https://my-site.com works for me

Answer (score 0):

It's working with cURL because the `-k` option skips verification of the server certificate. You can get similar behavior with `Net::HTTP`, but if you're going to make this a public site, you need to fix the server's configuration.

To get `-k` behavior in Ruby for now, set the `verify_mode`:

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```

Comment: I have tried that but I couldn't get it to work with my password and username. The endpoint is internal and requires ldap authentication. I ended up by hacking it (curl in my controller with credentials externally pulled).